# How to pair two stacks in ascending order using an array

Tags: c++

I have a template class for two stacks, but I don't know how I would go about pairing them to fill up one first and then the second. Any help or ideas would be much appreciated! Here is what I currently have.

```
    template<class Item> stackpair<Item>::stackpair()
    {

    };
    template<class Item> stackpair<Item>::stack_a()
    {
        used = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
        {
            data_first[i] = Item();
        }
    };
    template<class Item> stackpair<Item>::stack_b()
    {
        used = 0;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++)
        {
            data_second[i] = Item();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better for you to use an alias for a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) of two [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)s instead of defining a new class with similar functionality:

```
template<typename Item, std::size_t N>
using stackpair = std::pair<std::array<Item, N>, std::array<Item, N>>;
```

and instantiate them with:

```
stackpair<Example, CAPACITY> sp;
```

and [`fill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/fill) them with:

```
sp.first.fill(Example());
sp.second.fill(Example());
```

Also notice that there's a specific container for stack-like operations named [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).